# Android Gingerbread keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-source

I want to extend Android 2.3 Keyboard (LatinIme). I get source code from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME

After fixing some errors(missed classes) and packages rename, i can install it as bonus keyboard. But it doesn't work.

I see:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23089): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary

but name of my package is com.keyboard.latin and I delete all links to this missed class.

Can someone give me an advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: Very hard to answer without seeing the code, but note that the native C++ code also has a reference to it, in native/jni/com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary.cpp :
`const char* const kClassPathName = "com/android/inputmethod/latin/BinaryDictionary";`

Comment: You are completely right. By change this link and recompile native classes I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take some inspiration from [scandinavian-keyboard](http://code.google.com/p/scandinavian-keyboard/), it solves similar issue (I think it's Eclair or Froyo though, not updated to work with Gingerbread). It reimplements missing parts. If you look at its [sources](http://code.google.com/p/scandinavian-keyboard/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fandroid%2Finputmethod%2Fnorwegian) you'll see classes like `Dictionary`, `UserDictionaryProvider` etc. There's some C code too.

Comment: Missed classes really not a problem. Easy to find it using Google.